# Elements inside @guest tags shown, even though user is authenticated

Tags: php, html, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

As the title states, the content inside the guest tags is shown, even though the user is authenticated.

I want to display in the Navbar a dashboard route when the standard user is logged in, and a specific logout button when the "portal" user is logged in.

I got two guards in my auth.php file (One is the standard, portal is my custom):

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'portal' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'portals'
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'portal' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Portal::class,
        ],
```

Here is the code with the @auth tags in my app.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Finanzraketen</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <style>
        .hintergrund{
            background-image: url('/background.jpeg');
            background-size: cover;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="hintergrund">
<!-- Navbar goes here -->
<nav class="bg-white shadow-lg bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 mb-10">
    <div class="max-w-full mx-auto px-4">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <div class="flex space-x-7">
                <div>
                    <!-- Website Logo -->
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center py-4 px-2">
                        <img src="/rakete-2.png" alt="Logo" class="h-8 w-8 mr-2">
                        <span class="font-semibold text-black text-lg">Finanzraketen</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Primary Navbar items -->
                <div class="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-3 ">
                    <ul class="flex items-center pl-10 grid grid-cols-6 gap-10">
                    <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('home') }}" class="p-3">Home</a>

                    <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('overview') }}" class="p-3">Stellenanzeigen</a>

                        @auth('web')
                                <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" class="col-start-3 py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Dashboard</a>


                                <a href="" class="col-start-4 py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition border-gray-500
                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">{{ auth()->user()->email }}</a>


                                <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post" >
                                    @csrf
                                    <button type="submit" class="col-start-5 py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Logout</button>
                                </form>
                            @endauth

                            @auth('portal')
                            <form action="{{ route('portal_logout') }}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                <button type="submit" class="col-start-5 py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Portal Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        @endauth

                    @guest
                             <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('login') }}" class="p-3">Mitarbeiter Login</a>


                               <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('register') }}" class="p-3">Registrieren</a>

                            <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('portal_login') }}" class="p-3">Portal Login</a>

                            <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('portal_register') }}" class="p-3">Portal Registrieren</a>
                            @endguest

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Mobile menu button -->
            <div class="md:hidden flex items-center">
                <button class="outline-none mobile-menu-button">
                    <svg class=" w-6 h-6 text-black hover:text-green-400"
                         x-show="!showMenu"
                         fill="none"
                         stroke-linecap="round"
                         stroke-linejoin="round"
                         stroke-width="2"
                         viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                        <path d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- mobile menu -->
    <div class="hidden mobile-menu">
        <ul class="">

            <li> <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('overview') }}">Stellenanzeigen</a> </li>
            @auth()
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="" class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300">{{ auth()->user()->email }}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post" class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit">Logout</button>
                    </form>
                </li>

            @endauth

                @guest
                    <li>
                    <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('login') }}" class="p-3">Mitarbeiter Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('register') }}" class="p-3">Registrieren</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('portal_register') }}" class="p-3">Bewerbungsportal Login</a>
                    </li>
                @endguest
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector("button.mobile-menu-button");
        const menu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu");

        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
        });
    </script>
</nav>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.php file:

```
Route::get('home', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');


Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
Route::post('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'storePost']);


Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store'])->name('logout');


Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);


Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store']);


Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts');

Route::get('/index', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('overview');



Route::get('/portal/register', [PortalRegController::class, 'index'])->name('portal_register');

Route::post('/portal/register', [PortalRegController::class, 'store']);



Route::get('/portal/login', [PortalLoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('portal_login');

Route::post('/portal/login', [PortalLoginController::class, 'login'])->name('portal_login');

Route::post('/portal/logout', [PortalLogoutController::class, 'store'])->name('portal_logout');
```

I also tried implementing it the "ugly" way with `@if(Auth::guard('portal')->check()`
but it didn't change anything.

I am not sure whether you need Controller code too, but if so I will show it to you of course, just don't want to make the post unnecessarily larger.

Edit:  The `@auth('web')` works totally fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check authentication state of non-default guard, you should pass guard name to directive, like `@guest('portal')`, see here - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much. I feel so dumb right now, I tried something similar but it didn't work so I thought with multiple guards it doesn't work. fuck me. 
Thank you! Very appreciated :)